# Can someone help me understand this equation that finds derivative of quaternion when angular velocity is known?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics, complex-numbers

I found the following equation in an IEEE paper:

$\frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\text{Q}\omega$

where $q$ is the quaternion that rotates a vector from the body frame to the world, $q=\left[q(1), q(2), q(3), q(4)\right]^T$

$\omega$ is the angular velocity vector of the body frame with respect to the world frame represented in the body frame. $\omega = \left[\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z\right]^T$

and $\text{Q}$ (aka left matrix equivalent for quaternion multiplication) is a $4\times4$ matrix defined as

\begin{bmatrix}
q(1)& -q(2)& -q(3)&-q(4)\\
q(2)& q(1)& -q(4)& q(3)\\
q(3)& q(4)&q(1)&-q(2)\\
q(4)&-q(3)&q(2)&q(1)
\end{bmatrix}

$\text{Q}$ is $4\times 4$
 but $\omega$ is $3\times 1$. Should a zero be padded to make $\omega$ $4\times 1$?

I want to know if the mentioned equation is correct.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8421936

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Please typeset your formulas with MathJax. It would also be helpful if you could provide a link to the paper in question.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)